# Beginner cucumber query-cucumber feature file is not displayed in green colour

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am new in selenium and I have configured Cucumber with Maven and create one feature file but feature file's green icon is not displayed. Can I missed some configuration?
[Cucumber feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/198nk.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called **Natural 0.7.6** and it has a cucumber editor. If you download and install it from Eclipse Marketplace, then you will see the green icon for Cucumber feature file.

If you want to check the detailed steps, then please refer this article - [Add Cucumber feature file](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/add-cucumber-feature-file/)

Answer (score 0):

That is because your version of IntelliJ is not recognizing the feature extension. For that, in IntelliJ, go to File --> Settings --> Editor --> File Types --> Mark "Cucumber Scenario" and add Registered Patters the *.feature

[image: IntelliJ Settings]

The Cucumber green icon will be displayed the next tim you create a feature file.

Answer (score 0):

after installing Natural plugin, open .feature file and right click  on it. 
then choice option as >> open with  > others > from internal  editor please select the cucumber editor > then above the ok button checked mark on "use it for all "*.feature" files.
then you can see the all **.feature** file display green.

Answer (score 0):

inside feature folder , Right click on feature file->open with -> editior
Colour will appear if rest settings are correct. For  me , it worked